# replace text inside img title tag to create an image caption with a heading-subheading

Tags: jquery, string, dom, replace

I am using the NIVO slider javascript and want to create a caption for my images that has a header in bold and subhead in normal text. 
I would like to split the text into two separate elements by searching for a double colon(or similar) and replacing everything after that text with a span tag.

Can this be accomplished in jquery?

Answer (score 1):

For the replacement, you don't need jQuery at all. Given a string of text:

```
var mytext = "This is line one::this is line two";
```

...you can use `replace` with a regular expression, like this:

```
var newtext = mytext.replace(/^(.*)::(.*)$/i,'$1<span>$2</span>');
```

Given a string with a single known delimiter, you can do it by going through an array:

```
var mytext = "This is line one|This is line two";
var newtext = mytext.split('|'); // break into array
newtext = newtext[0] + '<span>' + newtext[1] + '</span>'; // back to string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = str.split(',');
// s[0] first line
// s[1] second line
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

Given HTML like this:

```
<div class="image">
    <img class="image" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3306/3498395482_c48e313ed9_s.jpg" />
</div>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
var caption = "Flamenco Beach::Wish I was there!";
var captionElements = caption.split("::");
$("div.image").append(
    "<span class='header'>" + captionElements[0] + "</span>" +
    "<span class='subheader'>" + captionElements[1] + "</span>");
```

And this CSS:

```
.header {
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
.subheader {
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}

.image { float:left; }
```

This will take the variable "caption" and break it into two spans, appending them beneath the image.

Check out the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/DXtzP/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jruddell/Mz3sE/

```
var text = $('.title').html().split('::'),
    newText = text[0] + '<b>' + text[1] + '</b>';

$('.title').html(newText);
```